# Can I consider operations of Union, Complement, Intersection in set theory, as functions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Recently started learning math and set theory on my own. I know the notion of Functions, but definitions do not use the word function in my book, e.g. [Intersection definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zapBk.png). I wonder, is it because it is assumed I do not know functions yet, or these operations aren't functions? Though, I thought all operations are functions...

Comment: Not functions "inside" the theory, because in set theory functions are simply a set with a specified property.

Comment: To be a function in the formal, set-theoretic sense, there needs to be a set that is the domain, and a set that is the codomain. But, unions, compliments, and intersections accept any general set, and the "collection" of all sets is, in a sense, too large to be a set itself. There are larger analogues of sets called "classes" where this will make sense, but for subtle reasons, you won't be viewing these operations as functions (even though, in a practical sense, they basically are functions).

Answer (score 0):

It is because set theory is the base stone. After you have set theory, then you can define function based on it. If you use function to describe intersection then it become a cycle and both of them are not well defined.